# GridSplitter to Resize from Right - Odd Behaviour

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid, gridsplitter

Using Kaxaml, resizing from the left works as expected.

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Grid>  

  <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" Background="DarkGray" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></GridSplitter>

    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="Red" Height="100"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="Yellow" Height="100"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Fill="Green" Height="100"/>
  </Grid>

  </Grid>
</Page>
```

However when trying something similar on the right it behaves very differently.

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Grid>  

  <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1"  Width="5" Background="DarkGray" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></GridSplitter>

    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="Red" Height="100"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="Yellow" Height="100"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Fill="Green" Height="100"/>
  </Grid>

  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Oddly only dragging right works and the size happens in an almost inverse manner.

Comment: Having exactly the same problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002846/weird-gridsplitter-resizing-behaviour).

Answer (score 0):

For the first column change `Width="*"` to `Width="Auto"`.